# repo init fails while cloning manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source, repo

I am trying to download android source using repo manifest but not able to proceed due to this error:

```
android@buildserver:~/aosp$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 128
  cwd: /home/android/aosp/.repo/repo
  cmd: ['git', 'config', 'remote.origin.url', 'https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo']
  stderr:
  >> fatal: not in a git directory
fatal: double check your --repo-rev setting.
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

I have repo installed properly,

```
android@buildserver:~/aosp$ repo version
<repo not installed>
repo launcher version 2.21
       (from /usr/local/bin/repo)
git 2.25.1
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
OS Linux 5.4.0-110-generic (#124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 14 19:46:19 UTC 2022)
CPU x86_64 (x86_64)
Bug reports: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/entry?template=Repo+tool+issue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory .repo/repo.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and the issue was directory permissions.

First remove the .repo directory, if it exists:

`rm -rf .repo/`

Take ownership of the current directory:

`chown -R <user> .`

Then try running `repo init` again.

I discovered the problem after doing as [n3d](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74086667/revisions) mentions, by adding the /path/to/my/stuff/.repo/repo.tmp directory to my .gitconfig. This then led to a cascade of more required exceptions, which need to be added one at a time because the git config doesn't support wildcards.